# Brake or Wheel Click under braking

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, clicking

I have a clicking from my rear wheel (sometimes in the front too), when applying my brakes. Sounds similar to a aluminum can tab being snapped, or can being flexed.

| Product | Brand | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Caliper | Shimano | R7070 |
| Pad | Shimano | L04C |
| Rotor | Campangolo | AFS 03 |

I have tried re-torqueing my rotors (40Nm), Brake calipers [Mount to frame] (8Nm), cleaning the pistons, pad spring and pads using iso 99%.

I have also tried cleaning where the spokes make contact both to the hub and with each other incase any grit from the beginning of the year.

There is movement in the spider of the rotor, however I would expect a little movement as it is a floating rotor design (space allowed between the rotor, rivet and spider for thermal expansion - at least I think).

I have also tried putting masking tape on either end of the pads as there was some room for the pads to move and I wasn't sure as the pad was being modulated if it was rattling in the caliper.

I have a couple of more attempts to identify the cause:

1. Switch the front and rear rotor to see if the noise moves to the front wheel
2. Switch the wheelset to my older one with different rotors.
3. Use the rotors from my old wheelset
4. Use my old resin pads with the current wheel set.
5. Give up and take it to the LBS.

Before I go further down this rabbit hole, I was wondering if anyone else has any ideas or experience in a similar problem?

---

Pad wear is at more than 50% left. The noise occurred maybe 2 weeks after they were installed.

Comment: Does the clicking sound occur once during initial engagement of the brakes or once per wheel revolution while you are dragging the brakes?

Comment: Hi Sean - you appear to have created a second account by mistake.  Please use your original account.  I'll delete the duplicate and merge the info.

Comment: "There is movement in the spider of the rotor, however I would expect a little movement as it is a floating rotor design (space allowed between the rotor, rivet and spider for thermal expansion - at least I think)." 

There should be no movement on the rotor itself. If anything it's the pads moving in the caliper

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply some grease to the spoke crossings, these can cause a clicking noise. In case of the rear wheel, the noise can also occur when pedaling, which is also solved this way. [Park Tool PPL-1](https://www.parktool.com/en-int/product/polylube-1000-lubricant-tube-ppl-1) worked well for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that could be from the pads moving in the caliper. The retaining pin allows the pads to have some lateral movement. You can test this by lightly pulling the brake whilst stationary and try and rotate the wheel.

Alternatively check your disc rotors are tightened correctly/to spec.